# How to find a point on an ellipse whose normal intersects a point outside the ellipse?

Tags: conic-sections

I'm not a math person or coder, so please be patient with me. If I have an ellipse using this equation:
$$\frac{(x-h)^2}{a^2}+\frac{\left(y-k\right)^2}{b^2}=1$$

And I know the values $a,b,h,k,x',y'$ how do I calculate the coordinates for a point on the ellipse where the normal intersects $x',y'$?

[image]

I did find this solution here:
[How to find the point on an ellipse that is closest to the point A outside of the ellipse](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2785107/how-to-find-the-point-on-an-ellipse-that-is-closest-to-the-point-a-outside-of-th)

But I don't understand how to use the equations, and also can't comment to ask for help because I don't have enough reputation points.

Much appreciated!

Comment: Why are you trying to do a problem where everything is a letter rather than an identified number? The earlier problem had the specific $x^2 + 4 y^2$ for example.

Comment: Because it's going in a script? I guess for simple example (h,k) can be at (0,0), b=1, a=2, and (x',y') is at (2,2), I just wanted to keep them variables so I can use it in a script later.

Answer (score 1):

> A central conic has at most $4$ concurrent normals from a given point.

Given an ellipse

$$\frac{(x-h)^2}{a^2}+\frac{(y-k)^2}{b^2}=1 \tag{1}$$

The equation of the normal at $(X,Y)$ is

$$\frac{(X-h)(y-Y)}{a^2}-\frac{(x-X)(Y-k)}{b^2}=0$$

If $B$, $C$, $D$ and $E$ are the feet (or pedals) of the concurrent normals from $A(x',y')$, then switching the roles of $(x,y)$ and $(X,Y)$ gives an Apollonian rectangular hyperbola

$$\frac{(x-h)(y-y')}{a^2}-\frac{(x'-x)(y-k)}{b^2}=0 \tag{2}$$

on which $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$ and $E$ are lying.  Hence, the intersections of $(1)$ and $(2)$ are the required feet of the concurrent normals.

[image]

- There will be $4$ concurrent normals when

$$[a(x'-h)]^{2/3}+[b(y'-k)]^{2/3}<(a^2-b^2)^{2/3}$$

- There will be $3$ concurrent normals when

$$[a(x'-h)]^{2/3}+[b(y'-k)]^{2/3}=(a^2-b^2)^{2/3}$$

that is $A$ lies on the ellipse evolute.

- There will be $2$ concurrent normals when

$$[a(x'-h)]^{2/3}+[b(y'-k)]^{2/3}>(a^2-b^2)^{2/3}$$

- For $a^2>2b^2$, part of the evolute will be outside the ellipse.  There'll be two to four normals concurrent at $(x',y')$.  The problem can be solved graphically by finding the intersections of the two conics.  The pictures are generated by [**Geogebra**](https://www.geogebra.org/).

> See my derivation for an oblique case of central conics [**here**](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1886700/where-would-the-four-normals-be/1887058#1887058) and also the case of [**hyperbola**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6FAmS.jpg) for your further interest.

Comment: OP admitted the solution in the linked thread was opaque to OP, so a discussion like this (including hyperbolas, which were not even asked for) will likely not be a usable answer for OP. (And they aren't for me neither,- i do not even see the normals' equations)

Comment: Ha, yea this is way over my head and also too complicated. I'm just looking for the solution to 'A' given here, I thought asking for the normal implied outward facing right angles because that is how it is used in 3D modeling, but I see here it means any right angle.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you want $(x',y')$ to be on the normal ray exterior to the ellipse, as shown in your diagram, your question is indeed looking for the point $(x,y)$ on the ellipse closest to $(x',y')$.
There could be as many as three other points from which a line normal to the ellipse intersects $(x',y')$, but I believe in all those cases the line will have to pass through the ellipse between $(x,y)$ and $(x',y')$.

For application to a software program, I think you're going to want to use a numerical root-finding function.

The coordinates of any point $(x,y)$ on the ellipse can be parameterized by
$$
\begin{align}
x &= h + a\cos\theta, \\
y &= k + b\sin\theta,
\end{align} \tag1
$$
where you can let $\theta$ range from $0$ to $2\pi$ if you want to cover every point on the ellipse.
The distance from $(x,y)$ to $(x',y')$ as a function of $\theta$ is then
$$
d(\theta) = \sqrt{(x' - h - a\cos\theta)^2 + (y' - k - b\sin\theta)^2}.
$$

So that's the function whose value you want to minimize.
Since the minimum value of $d(\theta)$ will coincide with the minimum value
of $(d(\theta))^2$, you can also solve this by minimizing
$$
f(\theta) = {(x' - h - a\cos\theta)^2 + (y' - k - b\sin\theta)^2}.
$$

You can restrict the possible values of $\theta$ depending on the location of $(x',y')$ relative to $(h,k)$, for example, if $x'>h$ and $y'>k$ then $(x',y')$ is in the first quadrant relative to the ellipse and therefore you only need to consider
$0 < \theta < \frac\pi2.$
Once you have made such a restriction, any point at which $f'(\theta) = 0$ will
be a point at minimum distance from $(x',y')$, because there are no inflection points in $f(\theta)$ and the restriction on $\theta$ rules out any maximum inside the interval. Now,
$$
f'(\theta) = 2a(x' - h - a\cos\theta)\sin\theta - 2b(y' - k - b\sin\theta)\cos\theta.
$$

So you just need to find $\theta$ such that
$$
a(x' - h - a\cos\theta)\sin\theta - b(y' - k - b\sin\theta)\cos\theta = 0.
$$
This is where a numerical root-finding function comes in handy.
If you cannot find one in any available math library for your script, one possibility is to implement the [bisection method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection_method),
which is not the most efficient method but is relatively simple to implement.

Once you find $\theta$ that minimizes $f(\theta),$ simply plug that value into Equation $(1)$ to get the desired values of $x$ and $y$.

Answer (score 0):

The parametric equations for the ellipse

$$ \dfrac{ (x - h)^2}{a^2} + \dfrac{ (y - k)^2}{b^2} = 1 $$

are:

$ x = h + a \cos t $

$ y = k + b \sin t $

The tangent vector is  $( - a \sin t, b \cos t ) $, therefore the normal vector is

$ (b \cos t , a \sin t ) $

Hence we want to find $s$ such that

$ (h + a \cos t , k + b \sin t ) + s (b \cos t, a \sin t ) = (x', y') $

It follows that $s$ is given by

$ s = \dfrac{ x' - h - a \cos t }{ b \cos t } = \dfrac{ y' - k - b \sin t }{a \sin t } $

Cross multiplying, gives us,

$ a \sin t ( x' - h - a \cos t ) - b \cos t ( y' - k - b \sin t ) = 0 $

This equation is of the form

$ A \cos t + B \sin t + C \cos(2 t) + D \sin(2 t) + E = 0 $

where

$A = - b (y' - k)$

$B = a (x' - h) $

$ C = 0 $

$ D = \dfrac{1}{2} ( - a^2 + b^2 ) $

$ E = 0 $

The standard way to solve this equation it to introduce the transformation $ z = \tan \dfrac{t}{2} $, then it follows that

$ \cos t = 2 \cos^2 \dfrac{t}{2}  - 1 = \dfrac{2}{z^2 + 1} - 1 = \dfrac{1 - z^2 }{1 + z^2} $

And similarly,

$ \sin t = 2 \cos \dfrac{t}{2} \sin \dfrac{t}{2} = 2 \cos^2 \dfrac{t}{2} \tan \dfrac{t}{2} = \dfrac{2z}{z^2 + 1} $

Using the above, we can find expressions for $\sin(2 t)$ and $\cos(2 t)$, namely

$ \sin(2 t) = 2 \sin t \ \cos t = \dfrac{ 4 z (1- z^2) }{(1 + z^2)^2} $

and

$ \cos(2 t) = 2 \cos^2 t - 1 = 2 \left( \dfrac{1 - z^2}{1 + z^2} \right)^2 - 1 = \dfrac{z^4 - 6 z^2 + 1 }{(1 + z^2)^2} $

Substituting these expressions in to the equation and multiplying through by $(1 + z^2)^2 $ results in a quartic (degree $4$) polynomial in $z$, which can be solved using the quartic polynomial roots formula, or numerically.  Once the $z$-roots are found, the angle $t$ corresponding to each root $z$ is computed as $ t = 2 \tan^{-1} z $.