# Find a point on an ellipse closest to a fixed point inside the ellipse

Tags: optimization, lagrange-multiplier

I want to find out ${(u,v)}$ on the ellipse $$\frac{u^2}{a^2}+\frac{v^2}{b^2}=1$$ for a point ${(x,y)}$ inside ellipse, which will denote shortest distance from $(x,y)$ to the ellipse boundary. I expressed this problem as a constrained optimization problem by this Lagrangian:

\begin{align}
L(u,v,\lambda) &= (u-x)^2+(v-y)^2-\lambda\left(\frac{u^2}{a^2} + \frac{v^2}{b^2}-1\right)\\[1ex]
\frac{\partial L(u,v,\lambda)}{\partial u}&=2u-2x-\frac{2\lambda u}{a^2}\\[1ex] 
\frac{\partial L(u,v,\lambda)}{\partial v}&=2v-2y-\frac{2\lambda v}{b^2}\\[1ex] 
\frac{\partial L(u,v,\lambda)}{\partial \lambda}&=\frac{u^2}{a^2}+\frac{v^2}{b^2}-1\\[1em]
u&=\frac{a^2x}{a^2-\lambda}\tag1\\[1ex]
v&=\frac{b^2y}{b^2-\lambda}\tag2\\[1ex]
\frac{u^2}{a^2}&+\frac{v^2}{b^2}-1=0\tag3\\
\end{align}

After substituting $u$ and $v$ in equation $(3)$, I get
\begin{aligned} 
\frac{a^2x^2}{(a^2-\lambda)^2}+\frac{b^2y^2}{(b^2-\lambda)^2}-1=0\\
\end{aligned}
I am getting a 4th degree equation of $\lambda$. I am facing difficulties in finding algebraic solution of the equation.

Comment: I am afraid that any one would be facing the same difficulties.

Comment: Your problem is equivalent to find a normal passing through a given point.  There're **two to four normals** which concurrent to the given point.  See another answer of mine [***here***](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2801211/how-to-find-a-point-on-an-ellipse-whose-normal-intersects-a-point-outside-the-el/2801747#2801747).