# How to find the general form of minimum distance from the point (m,n) to the ellipse by using Lagrange Multiplier?

Tags: conic-sections, lagrange-multiplier

Excuse me!

I have tried to solve this problem for a long time but I have stuck in this step.

[This is my work picture01.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YyLYR.jpg)

[This is my work picture02.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uJ17q.jpg)

I cannot simplify y in term of a b  m and n. It’s too complicated.

Could you guide me how to do this?
And Do you have any method to solve this equation?

Thank you very much

Comment: Related to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2801211/how-to-find-a-point-on-an-ellipse-whose-normal-intersects-a-point-outside-the-el) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3167029/find-a-point-on-an-ellipse-closest-to-a-fixed-point-inside-the-ellipse).

Answer (score 0):

You solve the first equation for $x$ and the second equation for $y$. Then you substitute both in the third equation. Unfortunately this results in a quartic equation in $\lambda$ which can be solved by Ferrari's method.

I don't think there is way around the forth order equation since depending on the position of the point $(m,n)$ there are up to four critical points.

Comment: I did try it but I found the equation of  λ in degree 4. I cannot solve this.

Comment: How to solve it?

Comment: I am sorry, you are right, I edited the answer.